Deploy GPU Based Application using Load Balancer with autoscalling groups
In the context of AI architecture, I am looking to optimize the distribution of API requests across multiple instances to efficiently utilize GPU resources. Specifically, I am interested in understanding the capabilities and mechanisms available for routing requests based on GPU utilization.
Can a load balancer be configured to route API requests according to the GPU memory utilization of each instance? If so, how can this be implemented effectively? Alternatively, are there other mechanisms or best practices that allow for the dynamic allocation of requests based on GPU usage to ensure optimal performance and scalability of AI services?
I have try with aws application load balancer with the policy of round robin and I am expecting the load balancer only send the request on that server which have GPU capacity.

You can achieve routing of incoming HTTP requests associated with GPU-intensive task to your applications running on top of GPU instances by combining Listener Rules for your ALBs, target groups and a bit of application refactoring.
One of the many ways to implement this with the least amount of refactoring is by:

Splitting the application's HTTP endpoints between GPU-intensive and Non GPU-intensive APIs (This means that you need two sets of applications running those APIs).
Since you have split your application into two, you can now have two auto-scaling and target groups, the first group is in charge of the non-gpu intensive workload and the second one will be in charge of the gpu-intensive workload.
You can then define ALB listener rules in such a way that any Non GPU-intensive API starts with /apis and GPU-intensive task starts with /gpu-apis.
The HTTP listener for endpoints starting with /apis needs to be redirected to the target group of the non-gpu intensive workloads.
The HTTP listener for endpoints starting with /gpu-apis needs to be redirected to the target group of the gpu-intensive workloads.

Below is a terraform code used to define a load balancer that implements this:
resource "aws_lb" "alb" {
  name               = "my-alb"
  internal           = false
  load_balancer_type = "application"
  security_groups    = [aws_security_group.alb.id]
  subnets            = [aws_subnet.subnet1.id, aws_subnet.subnet2.id]

  enable_deletion_protection = false
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group" "non_gpu" {
  name     = "non-gpu-targets"
  port     = 80
  protocol = "HTTP"
  vpc_id   = aws_vpc.main.id
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group" "gpu" {
  name     = "gpu-targets"
  port     = 80
  protocol = "HTTP"
  vpc_id   = aws_vpc.main.id
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "https" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.alb.arn
  port              = "443"
  protocol          = "HTTPS"
  ssl_policy        = "ELBSecurityPolicy-2016-08"

  certificate_arn = "arn:aws:acm:us-west-2:123456789012:certificate/your-certificate-id" # Replace with your ACM certificate ARN

  default_action {
    type = "fixed-response"
    fixed_response {
      content_type = "text/plain"
      message_body = "404: Not Found"
      status_code  = "404"
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "non_gpu_rule" {
  listener_arn = aws_lb_listener.https.arn
  priority     = 10

  action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.non_gpu.arn
  }

  condition {
    field  = "path-pattern"
    values = ["/apis/*"]
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "gpu_rule" {
  listener_arn = aws_lb_listener.https.arn
  priority     = 20

  action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.gpu.arn
  }

  condition {
    field  = "path-pattern"
    values = ["/gpu-apis/*"]
  }
}


resource "aws_instance" "non_gpu_instance" {
  count         = 2 # Adjust the count as necessary
  ami           = "ami-0c55b159cbfafe1f0" # Use the appropriate AMI for your region
  instance_type = "t3.micro" # Use a non-GPU instance type

  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.alb.id]
  subnet_id              = aws_subnet.subnet1.id

  tags = {
    Name = "non-gpu-instance"
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "gpu_instance" {
  count         = 2 # Adjust the count as necessary
  ami           = "ami-0c55b159cbfafe1f0" # Use the appropriate AMI for your region
  instance_type = "g4dn.xlarge" # Use a GPU-optimized instance type

  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.alb.id]
  subnet_id              = aws_subnet.subnet2.id

  tags = {
    Name = "gpu-instance"
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "non_gpu_attachment" {
  count            = length(aws_instance.non_gpu_instance[*].id)
  target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.non_gpu.arn
  target_id        = element(aws_instance.non_gpu_instance[*].id, count.index)
  port             = 80
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "gpu_attachment" {
  count            = length(aws_instance.gpu_instance[*].id)
  target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.gpu.arn
  target_id        = element(aws_instance.gpu_instance[*].id, count.index)
  port             = 80
}

Another approach is to just extract the GPU-intensive routines in your application so that they'd be running as a background worker that sits on top of your GPU-optimized instances. Consider using EventBridge and SQS for offloading the GPU-intensive routines to the background worker.
